# CarouFredSel Flashes When Scrolling Next in Safari

Tags: jquery, google-maps, safari, scroll, caroufredsel

I am working on a website that uses CarouFredSel to display a vertical scroller (http://new.joshrodg.com/?page_id=206), the problem I'm having is when I click the previous button, CarouFredSel scrolls just fine...but when I try and advance the slideshow by clicking the next button the scrolling is messed up....and the odd thing is that it happens only when I have posted a Google Map using the WordPress MapPress plugin.

I am pretty sure the MapPress plugin is causing the issue, but I think with some code it can be fixed (especially since it seems this is a Safari-only issue...I've tested it in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, and IE8)

Now one thing that did work (somewhat) was adding `position: relative` to my `.sidebar-image a` css style, the only problem with that is that although it advances correctly, there is no scrolling effect (which defeats the purpose)

Anyone ever experienced this before?

My `script` looks like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* Sidebar */
    $("#sidebar-image").carouFredSel({
        direction: "up",
        auto: false,
        items: {
            visible: 2
        },
        next: "#down",
        prev: "#up",
        scroll: {
            easing: "quadratic",
            items: 1
        },
        width: "100%"
    });
});
```

My `code` looks like:

```
<div class="sidebar-image">
    <div id="sidebar-image">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <?php 
                    $id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, "large", true);
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $url[0]; ?>" rel="lightbox[<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>]"><?php the_post_thumbnail("sidebar-image"); ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <!-- -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and my `CSS` looks like:

```
/* Slides */
.sidebar-image {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdedf;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 277px;
}

.sidebar-image a {
    border-left: 1px solid #dcdedf;
    border-right: 1px solid #dcdedf;
    border-top: 1px solid #dcdedf;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

All of this  code is in another div that has a relative position - I read somewhere that that could cause the problem, but even after removing the css the carousel still does the same thing...

The `code` for the containing div looks like:

```
/* Slideshow */
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 305px;
}
```

I have tried using a different jQuery library (the one straight from jQuery, as opposed to the one straight from Google). I have also tried using the the full CarouFredSel script, as opposed to using the CarouFredSel packed version.

Any ideas? It's got me stumped :-(

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that this is a Google Maps issue and has nothing to do with the code I am using for CarouFredSel...I have tried several Google Map plugins for WordPress and the crazy scrolling happens regardless of the plugin.

So, here's what I did...instead of using the Google Maps plugin called: "MapPress", I am using the MapQuest plugin called: "MapQuest Map Builder for WordPress"

Now, on any post or page with a map the CarouFredSel code works without glitch or error :-)

Yay!

Thanks,
Josh